# Noodle.js Setup/jQuery Process (Web Scraping Help!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I've already installed noodle.js through npm install, and this what is what my code like this right now. However when I run this file (noodleTest.js) in the terminal: node noodleTest.js, I get the following error: jQuery.getJSON is not a function. I've looked at the majority of the stack overflow answers regarding this issue and couldn't find a fix. Through the example provided by http://noodlejs.com it returns an array in the console, but when I attempt to run this snippet I receive an error. Any help is appreciated.

```
var noodle = require('noodlejs'),
jQuery = require ('jquery');

var query = {
        url: 'http://google.com/search?q=javascript',
        type: 'html',
        selector: 'h3.r a',
        extract: 'text'
    },
    uriQuery = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query)),
    request  = 'http://example.noodlejs.com/?q=' +
        uriQuery + '&callback=?';

// Make Ajax request to Noodle server
jQuery.getJSON(request, function (data) {
    console.log(data[0].results);
});
```

***Edit***: I tried following the example given at
http://%20github.com/dharmafly/noodle#noodle-as-a-node-module, and used the example run give at noodlejs.com, but I'm not sure how to read the data, or how to extract the contents in the object.
var noodle = require('noodlejs');

```
noodle.query({
    url:      'http://google.com/search?q=javascript',
    selector: 'h3.r a',
    extract:  'text'
}) 
.then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

This is the following output:

```
 [noodle log  #1]
 Thu Jul 07 2016 00:09:43 GMT-0700 (PDT)
 Memory: 18.00mb (18870272 bytes)
 Noodle: The query follows...
 {"url":"http://google.com/search?q=javascript","selector":"h3.r a","extract":"text","type":"html","cache":true}


 [noodle log  #2]
 Thu Jul 07 2016 00:09:44 GMT-0700 (PDT)
 Memory: 19.00mb (19918848 bytes)
 Cache: Page has been cached


 [noodle log  #3]
 Thu Jul 07 2016 00:09:44 GMT-0700 (PDT)
 Memory: 20.00mb (20967424 bytes)
 Cache: Result has been cached

{ results: [ { results: [Object], created: 2016-07-07T07:09:44.286Z } ] }
```

Comment: Did you try the example without the jquery? you can find it here https://github.com/dharmafly/noodle#noodle-as-a-node-module or is jquery is something that you need to use?

Comment: Thank you for the replying, I've spent some time trying to understand how to read the results it's giving back, but I'm not able to figure this out, is there a certain way to access the contents of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a noodle query that works. Don't pay attention to the little details of what we are scrapping, look at the selector I asked for and what I wanted to be extracted.

As you can there's a selector which I picked randomly from the page, and the data extracted is text. But to see the extracted text look what I did with the results.

```
var noodle = require('noodlejs');

noodle.query({
  url:      'http://edition.cnn.com/',
  selector: '#intl_homepage1-zone-1 > div.l-container > div > div.column.zn__column--idx-0 > ul > article > a > h2',
  extract:  'text'
})
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(results.results[0]);

  });
```

The results are chained I didn't really check why maybe if you research you can make better use of it, but if you go into results twice as you can see what I have did you will eventually get to the information you wanted to extract.

Comment: Thank you for consistently helping! Yeah this definitely made a lot of things much clear, and I wasn't to sure why the results was chained, but I guess going into the results twice is just returning the array which is great!